Container running on Podman can ping host machine's private network IP address but cannot connect to service listening on that address
I have a fairly simple Dockerfile:
ARG CONTAINER_BASE_IMAGE
FROM ${CONTAINER_BASE_IMAGE}

COPY /buildenv_vars.sh /root/buildenv_vars.sh

RUN touch /root/.profile && cat /root/buildenv_vars.sh >> /root/.profile

# For debugging Ubuntu container, uncomment this line
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bind9-host iputils-ping telnet && setcap cap_net_raw+p /usr/bin/ping

CMD [ \
    "/bin/bash", \
    "-l", "-c", \
    "echo TSH=$TSH; echo TBH=$TBH; echo PATH=$PATH; echo Waiting for signal...; trap \"echo Shutting down; exit 0\" SIGTERM SIGINT SIGKILL; /bin/sleep infinity & wait" \
]

In my particular case at this time, $CONTAINER_BASE_IMAGE is ubuntu:jammy. Then I have this fairly simple Compose file:
services:
  container1:
    image: "${NAT_TRAV_IMG}"
    volumes:
      - "${TSH}:${TSH}"
      - "${TBH}:${TBH}"
    ports:
      - "${NAT_TRAV_EM_PORT:-44100}:${NAT_TRAV_EM_PORT:-44100}"

  container1:
    image: "${NAT_TRAV_IMG}"
    volumes:
      - "${TSH}:${TSH}"
      - "${TBH}:${TBH}"
    ports:
      - "${NAT_TRAV_SUB_PORT:-44200}:${NAT_TRAV_SUB_PORT:-44200}"

I start the containers using podman-compose up -d, and then podman-compose ps shows this:
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                     COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                     NAMES
0acc4de1b578  localhost/me/myimagename  /bin/bash -l -c e...  10 minutes ago  Up 10 minutes  0.0.0.0:44286->44286/tcp  mydirectoryname_container1_1
52d81a75c453  localhost/me/myimagename  /bin/bash -l -c e...  10 minutes ago  Up 10 minutes  0.0.0.0:44386->44386/tcp  mydirectoryname_container2_1

Furthermore, the command podman inspect -f '{{.Name}}:|:{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' shows that my container’s IP addresses are 10.89.2.2 and 10.89.2.3, respectively. So far so good. But here’s where things get a little confusing:
My host machine has the IP 172.24.52.166 on the local private network, and it has a service listening on port 46541 on that IP address (and only that IP address … not on 127.0.0.1 or anything else, and I can’t change that). My host machine’s firewall is disabled:
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

Other machines on the 172.24.52/24 network can ping my host machine and can telnet-connect (using telnet for simplistic connectivity test) to that listening service on port 46541:
$ ping 172.24.52.166
PING 172.24.52.166 (172.24.52.166): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.24.52.166: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.073 ms
64 bytes from 172.24.52.166: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.868 ms
64 bytes from 172.24.52.166: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.975 ms
^C
--- 172.24.52.166 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.868/0.972/1.073/0.084 ms

$ telnet 172.24.52.166 46541
Trying 172.24.52.166...
Connected to 172.24.52.166.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.

I also need my containers to be able to be able to connect to that service running on the host machine. When I “shell into” my container using (for example) the command podman exec -it mydirectoryname_container2_1 /bin/bash -l, it can ping 172.24.52.166, but it cannot telnet-connect to 172.24.52.166 on port 46541:
root@52d81a75c453:/# ping 172.24.52.166
PING 172.24.52.166 (172.24.52.166) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.24.52.166: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
64 bytes from 172.24.52.166: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from 172.24.52.166: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
^C
--- 172.24.52.166 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2029ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.063/0.065/0.067/0.001 ms

root@52d81a75c453:/# telnet 172.24.52.166 46541
Trying 172.24.52.166...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

I don’t feel like I’m doing anything fancy or difficult here, so I’m not sure why I can’t connect. FWIW:
$ podman-compose --version
podman-compose version 1.2.0
podman version 5.3.1

$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
...

Also, my container can access the internet just fine, and before I added the apt-get commands to the Dockerfile to streamline my debugging, I was running apt-get just fine within the running container as well. The problem appears to be limited to connecting to the host machine for something other than pinging.
I haven’t tried Docker yet. I’m probably going to try that next to see if maybe Podman is the problem, but I wanted to get this working with Podman.

It looks like the service you are connecting to is only accepting connections from the 172... network. Can you check from another network not linked to your containers?

Good idea, but no dice. I started up a virtual machine using NAT. Its IP address was 10.0.2.15. It could both ping 172.24.52.166 and telnet 172.24.52.166 46541 successfully.

So, Christmas break and all ... I finally got around to installing Docker and trying this out with that. Using the exact same steps but with docker and docker compose instead of podman and podman-compose, it all works as expected. I can connect from the container to my service running on port 46541 on the host machine. This appears to be a Podman bug.
